# Python - Reading Powershell script output, using subprocess, want to receive stdout line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, tkinter

Been Trying to read stdout from a Powershell script that runs for a little bit, generating output based on the number of computers it's pinging.

Trying to get the data to stream into the text box, but after all I've tried, I only seem to be able to get it to give all the output at once.

Been trying not to use `subprocess.communicate()`, as it also seems to give all the output at once.

Here is the Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


window = Tk()
window.title( 'PowerShell Script Temp' )

frame = Frame(window)

fldrPath = r"C:/Users/firstname.lastname/Downloads/Powershell Development/Monthly Scans/"

listbox = Listbox(frame)
listbox.configure(width=50)

for name in os.listdir(fldrPath):
    listbox.insert('end', name)

def selection():
    fileList = listbox.curselection()
    for file in fileList:
        os.chdir(fldrPath)
        
        # Right here is the problematic section
        with Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
                   universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                output.insert('end', line)
                print(line, end='')   

output = Text(window, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="white")

btn = Button(frame, text='Run Script', command=selection)

btn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
frame.pack(padx=30, pady=30)
output.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

[Doesn't filter line-by-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcGDx.png) - just vomits it all after the PS script has finished.

I've tried quite a few other things:

## Attempt 1

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    while proc.poll() is None:
         data = proc.stdout.readline()  # Alternatively proc.stdout.read(1024)
         print(data)
         text_box.insert('end', data)
```

## Attempt 2

```
outpipe = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)],
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    text_box.insert("end", outpipe)
```

## Attempt 3

```
with Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
         universal_newlines=True) as p, StringIO() as buf:
         for line in p.stdout:
             print(line, end='')
             buf.write(line)
         outpipe = buf.getvalue()
         output.insert('end', outpipe)
```

## Attempt 4

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)], shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     while proc.poll() is None:
         p = proc.stdout.readline()
         output.insert('end', p)
```

I've actually attempted far more, but can't seem to remember them.  Lots of fors and withs...I'm a bit tired of it at this point . I can get this thing to `Print()` in a manner that I desire, but not stream into the text box; almost like `.insert()` is too slow.

If someone could lead me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Tried almost every similar thread on here that I could manage, just doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: `Attempt 4` works fine in my Python 3.8.5 in Windows 10 with changing `shell=True` to `bufsize=1, universal_newlines=1`.

Comment: @acw1668 Hmm - I'm running the same setup, and still only get the final output in one chunk.

Comment: Try adding `output.update()` after `output.insert(...)` in `attempt 4`.

Comment: @acw1668 That was it.  I swear I tried every permutation, including using `.update()`, but this combo did the trick.  Thanks so much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to get the data to stream into the text box, but after all I've
> tried, I only seem to be able to get it to give all the output at
> once.

This code here:

```
def selection():
    fileList = listbox.curselection()
    for file in fileList:
        os.chdir(fldrPath)
        
        # Right here is the problematic section
        with Popen(["powershell.exe", '-File', fldrPath + '\\' + listbox.get(file)], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
                   universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                output.insert('end', line)
                print(line, end='')
```

is executed and after its finished you can see what it has done. To update it you could use the `after` method of tkinter and check for changes in the given time.
Like in this exampel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234732/13629335).

The tkinter mainloop works like [this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+event+loop)

```
     Start
       |
       |<----------------------------------------------------------+
       v                                                           ^
   Do I have    No[*]  Calculate how            Sleep for at       |
   work to do?  -----> long I may sleep  -----> most that much --->|
       |                                        time               |
       | Yes                                                       |
       |                                                           |
       v                                                           |
   Do one callback                                                 |
       |                                                           |
       +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Another suggestion would be to use another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416839/13629335).
Also you should read that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770371/13629335) for `.communicate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following :

```
command1 = "please type command whose output you want to achieve"
output1 = os.popen(command1).read()
print(output1)
```

Not sure man but i hope it works out for you